# Transfer data from multiple rows per year to one row per year in R

Tags: r

How do I transform data from multiple rows per year

```
Year type N
1    1    10
1    2    20
2    1    10
2    2    10
```

to one row per year with multiple columns

```
Year type1 type2 total
1    10     20    30
2    10     10    20
```

Comment: Provide reproducible data and expected ouput nex time. Makes it easier to answer your question and may be the reason for downvote

Answer (score 3):

An option would be to `paste` the 'type' string in the type column, `spread` to. 'wide' format. and then create the 'total' by adding the 'type1' and 'type2' columns

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   mutate(type = str_c("type", type)) %>%
   spread(type, N) %>%
   mutate(total =type1 + type2)
```